# BeautifulSoup4 Получить контент в зависимости от тега h3 и удалить этот тег

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Получаю такой HTML-код при парсинге:

```
<div class="row tab-pane" id="tab-description">

  <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Описание Makita 4329 Лобзик электрический</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Новый эргономичный дизайн </span></li>
            <li><span>Удобная D-образная рукоятка с резиновыми вставками </span></li>
            <li>Маятниковый ход </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Характеристики Makita 4329 Лобзик электрический</h3>
        <table class="reviewtab table table-striped">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Производитель</td>
                    <td class="odd" itemprop="brand"> Makita </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Страна происхождения</td>
                    <td class="odd"> Япония </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Штрих код:</td>
                    <td class="odd">088381083102</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

В нем есть нужные мне 2 div'a, с классами "col-md-6".
Мне нужно получить из них все кроме h3, вот пример:

получаю Описание

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Новый эргономичный дизайн </span></li>
    <li><span>Удобная D-образная рукоятка с резиновыми вставками </span></li>
    <li>Маятниковый ход </li>
</ul>
```

получаю Характеристики

```
<table class="reviewtab table table-striped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Производитель</td>
            <td class="odd" itemprop="brand"> Makita </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Страна происхождения</td>
            <td class="odd"> Япония </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Штрих код:</td>
            <td class="odd">088381083102</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Вот с какими проблемами я столкнулся:

1) Может быть такое, что один из блоков отсутствует и нужно как-то "понять", где Описание, а где Характеристики. За что в таком случае зацепится и какие методы библиотеки при этом задействовать?

2) Как мне удалить ненужные мне h3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете найти тег `h3` в `div` и извлечь из него первое слово, которое и будет говорить о назначении блока. А затем использовать метод `extract`, чтобы удалить его после анализа.

***Пример:***

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    with open('index.html', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        html = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'col-md-6'})
    for div in divs:
        h3 = div.find('h3')
        title = h3.get_text().split()[0]
        h3.extract()

        print(f'{title}:')
        print(div.prettify())
        print('=' * 73, end='\n\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```html
Описание:
<div class="col-md-6">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <span>
    Новый эргономичный дизайн
   </span>
  </li>
  <li>
   <span>
    Удобная D-образная рукоятка с резиновыми вставками
   </span>
  </li>
  <li>
   Маятниковый ход
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

=========================================================================

Характеристики:
<div class="col-md-6">
 <table class="reviewtab table table-striped">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Производитель
    </td>
    <td class="odd" itemprop="brand">
     Makita
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Страна происхождения
    </td>
    <td class="odd">
     Япония
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     Штрих код:
    </td>
    <td class="odd">
     088381083102
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>

=========================================================================
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно извлечь из кода все заголовки h3 вместе с их содержимым, используя регулярное выражение `<h3>.*</h3>` (т.е. `<h3> любая последовательность символов </h3>`).

Проблема заключается только в том, что если внутри "тела" div-а есть другие `<h3></h3>`, они тоже будут исключены.

Если внутри "тела" нет заголовков третьего уровня - просто высекай все результаты вхождений регулярного выражения `<h3>.*</h3>` через библиотеки работы с регулярными выражениями (в зависимости от языка, на котором осуществляется парсинг)

## UPD:

Чтобы отличать, где описание, а где характеристики, можно сначала проверять, есть ли в div-е регулярка `<h3>Описание.*</h3>` или `<h3>Характеристики.*</h3>` соответственно, по наличию этих регулярок определять тип блока, а уже потом удалять h3, как было указано выше

Comment: [_Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/11558617).